# ¿Cómo decir con operadores lógicos que por cada veces x número se vaya incrementando?

Tags: jquery

hola chicos estoy trabajando en un código que utiliza setInterval, estoy tratando que cada vez que cuente diez un x numero se vaya incrementando en 1
pero no se como usar los operadores lógicos en ese caso e aquí mi código espero vuestra ayuda gracias!

```js
/*este codigo hace girar unas imagenes*/
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};
$(document).ready(function(){


  /*la funcion carcher se ejecuta al cargar la pagina y comienzan a girar las imagenes y empieza el contador*/      
 function catcher(){
  var inter;
  var count = 0;
  var angle = 0;
  inter=setInterval(function(){
   $("#contador").html( count++);
    angle+=20;
  $(".image").rotate(angle);
  if(count==100){ 
$("#contador").html( count=1);
   $("#contador2").html( count++); //aqui es el problema nececito que por cada 100 milisegundos esta variable se vaya incrementando en 1 
     $(".image").css("width","80px").css("height","80px");
    }


  },100);
  
  /*si haces click detenemos la funcion o la ejecutamos dependiendo del estado */ $(".image").click(function(){
 
          if(angle > 0 ){
          angle=0;
         clearInterval(inter);
        }else{
          count=0
          angle=0;
          inter= setInterval(function(){
          $("#contador").html( count++); 
          angle+=20;
          $(".image").rotate(angle);
          
           if(count==100){ alert("tiempo agotado")}

       },100);
           
            

             }
    })  
 }
        
catcher();
     
})
```

```html
<img class="image"id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<div id="contador"></div>
<div id="contador2"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

como veran en mi codigo trato de que por cada 100 milisengundos la variable count se vaya incrementado en 1,2,3,4,5 etc.. hay algun operador logico que diga que por cada 100 cuente 1++? espero su ayuda chicos gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque simplemente no usas otra variable.  Algo asi:

```js
/*este codigo hace girar unas imagenes*/
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    return $(this);
};
$(document).ready(function(){


  /*la funcion carcher se ejecuta al cargar la pagina y comienzan a girar las imagenes y empieza el contador*/      
 function catcher(){
  var inter;
  var count = 0;
  var count2 = 1
  var angle = 0;
  inter=setInterval(function(){
   $("#contador").html( count++);
    angle+=20;
  $(".image").rotate(angle);
  if(count==100){ 
$("#contador").html( count=1);
   $("#contador2").html( count2++); //aqui es el problema nececito que por cada 100 milisegundos esta variable se vaya incrementando en 1 
     $(".image").css("width","80px").css("height","80px");
    }


  },100);
  
  /*si haces click detenemos la funcion o la ejecutamos dependiendo del estado */ $(".image").click(function(){
 
          if(angle > 0 ){
          angle=0;
         clearInterval(inter);
        }else{
          count=0
          angle=0;
          inter= setInterval(function(){
          $("#contador").html( count++); 
          angle+=20;
          $(".image").rotate(angle);
          
           if(count==100){ alert("tiempo agotado")}

       },100);
           
            

             }
    })  
 }
        
catcher();
     
})
```

```html
<img class="image"id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<img class="image" id="image" src="arrows.png" width="30px" height="30px">
<div id="contador"></div>
<div id="contador2"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hey no se me avia ocurrido antes gracias amigo!!

Comment: De nada @andygibbs